# Input reaction is slow in two player snake game

Tags: c++, input, snake

i'm trying to make a two player console snake game. One of the snakes is controled by 'wasd' and other 'uhjk'. I have two function to get the keys `getKEYS1()` and `getKEYS2()`. Only difference is the expected chars.

```
void Snake::getKEYS1()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'w':
            if (dir1 != down)  // 1
                dir1 = up;
            break;
        case 'a':
            if (dir1 != right) // 3
                dir1 = left;
            break;
        case 's':
            if (dir1 != up) // 2
                dir1 = down;
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (dir1 != left)  // 4
                dir1 = right;
            break;
        case 'r':  //to kill
            dir1 = kill;
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And to move the head i use the `Move()` function for both snakes.

```
void Snake::Move(Directions dir)
{

    //getKEYS1();
    //getKEYS2();

    switch (dir)
    {
    case Snake::stop:
        break;
    case Snake::up:
        headY--;
        break;
    case Snake::down:
        headY++;
        break;
    case Snake::left:
        headX--;
        break;
    case Snake::right:
        headX++;
        break;
    case Snake::kill:
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    //adjusting & balancing speed
    if (dir == down || dir == up) Sleep(30);
    else Sleep(7.5);

    //if sneake goes out of borders
    if (headX > width - 2) headX = 1;
    else if (headX < 1) headX = width - 1;

    if (headY > height - 2) headY = 1;
    else if (headY < 1) headY = height - 1;

    //return;
}
```

I can print both snakes to screen but when i try to move, they move with a huge delay.

```
    Snake s;

    std::vector<Snake> Snakes;
    Snakes.push_back(s);
    Snakes.push_back(s);

    bo.Render(screenBuffer);  //render borders to inner buffer
    Snakes[0].Render(screenBuffer);  //render snake1 to inner buffer
    Snakes[1].Render(screenBuffer);  //render snake2 to inner buffer
    screenBuffer->RenderToScreen();  //render all to screen
    screenBuffer->Clear();  //updating the screen
    Snakes[0].getKEYS1();
    Snakes[0].Move(Snakes[0].dir1);
    Snakes[1].getKEYS2();
    Snakes[1].Move(Snakes[1].dir2);
```

I think i call getKEYS2() but program tries to run getKEYS1() too and that's why reaction is slow. Am i wrong? What causes this problem? And what to do to avoid it?
If you need more info to understand the problem, please let me know.

I'm new to C++ so i stuck a little here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think i call getKEYS2() but program tries to run getKEYS1() too and that's why reaction is slow. Am i wrong?

You are wrong. C++ does not randomly call a completely different function with a similar name unless you ask it to.

The problem here is your logic. In each of these methods you get a key, any key that's been pressed, but then check only if it's a particular player's input. If that key you detected was for the opposite player, it's ignored. You're counting on `_kbhit` and `_getch` to filter to only return you one player's keys, but those functions don't know anything about that.

You perceive a delay because you're leaving it up to chance which key presses you act on, based on the order they come in.

Let's say player 1 presses and holds `w` at the same moment player 2 presses and holds `u`. For whatever hardware reason, the `u` gets detected first, so your console input buffer this frame reads `uw`.

You run `getKeys1()` and pull the first character out of the buffer, `u`, then check if it's any of player 1's keys. It's not, so you don't do anything with it. Then you run `getKeys2()` and pull the next character out of the buffer, `w`, and check if it's any of player 2's keys. It's not, so this input is also unhandled.

If the players keep holding the keys, the console will read `uwuwuwuwuw` with new characters getting added at the configured key repeat rate. So this pattern will repeat every frame until one player lets go of a key.

Player 2's input will only ever be correctly handled on frames where you're lucky enough that player 1 also pressed a key and it was added to the buffer before player 2's.

So, you need to rethink the way you're handling this input. Read the input buffer in a loop, and check the resulting character against *both* players' keys. That way, the input gets handled correctly no matter how many keys were pressed this frame, or the order they were detected and stored.